# I'm getting json string and i need to use that json string create the ui dynamically using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have JSON data like this

```
[
  {
    "Time Period": {
      "Point in Time": {
        "Monthly": {
          "2017": {
            "January": "January",
            "February": "February",
            "March": "March",
            "April": "April",
            "May": "May",
            "June": "June",
            "July": "July",
            "August": "August",
            "September": "September",
            "October": "October",
            "November": "November",
            "December": "December"
          },
          "2016": {
            "January": "January",
            "February": "February",
            "March": "March",
            "April": "April",
            "May": "May",
            "June": "June",
            "July": "July",
            "August": "August",
            "September": "September",
            "October": "October",
            "November": "November",
            "December": "December"
          },
          "2015": {
            "January": "January",
            "February": "February",
            "March": "March",
            "April": "April",
            "May": "May",
            "June": "June",
            "July": "July",
            "August": "August",
            "September": "September",
            "October": "October",
            "November": "November",
            "December": "December"
          },
          "2014": {
            "January": "January",
            "February": "February",
            "March": "March",
            "April": "April",
            "May": "May",
            "June": "June",
            "July": "July",
            "August": "August",
            "September": "September",
            "October": "October",
            "November": "November",
            "December": "December"
          }
        }
      },
      "Trend": {
        "Monthly": {
          "2017": {
            "January": "January",
            "February": "February",
            "March": "March",
            "April": "April",
            "May": "May",
            "June": "June",
            "July": "July",
            "August": "August",
            "September": "September",
            "October": "October",
            "November": "November",
            "December": "December"
          },
          "2016": {
            "January": "January",
            "February": "February",
            "March": "March",
            "April": "April",
            "May": "May",
            "June": "June",
            "July": "July",
            "August": "August",
            "September": "September",
            "October": "October",
            "November": "November",
            "December": "December"
          },
          "2015": {
            "January": "January",
            "February": "February",
            "March": "March",
            "April": "April",
            "May": "May",
            "June": "June",
            "July": "July",
            "August": "August",
            "September": "September",
            "October": "October",
            "November": "November",
            "December": "December"
          },
          "2014": {
            "January": "January",
            "February": "February",
            "March": "March",
            "April": "April",
            "May": "May",
            "June": "June",
            "July": "July",
            "August": "August",
            "September": "September",
            "October": "October",
            "November": "November",
            "December": "December"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Country": {
      "Tier1": {
        "Germany": null,
        "UK": null,
        "ITALY": null,
        "INDIA": null,
        "SOUTH AFRICA": null
      },
      "Tier2": {
        "Netherlands": null,
        "Ireland": null,
        "Portugal": null,
        "Greece": null
      }
    },
    "Columns": {
      "Brand": {
        "Vodafone": "Vodafone",
        "1&1": "1&1",
        "Airtel": "Airtel",
        "O2": "O2",
        "Unity Media": "Unity Media"
      },
      "Demographics": {
        "Gender": {
          "Male": "Male",
          "FeMale": "FeMale"
        },
        "Age Group": {
          "18-30": "18-30",
          "30-50": "30-50"
        },
        "Region": {
          "North": "North",
          "South": "South",
          "East": "East",
          "West": "West"
        },
        "House Hold Composition": {
          "House Hold composition1": "House Hold composition1",
          "House Hold composition2": "House Hold composition2"
        }
      }
    },
    "Rows": {
      "Main Measure": {
        "Brand": {
          "Vodafone": "Vodafone",
          "1&1": "1&1",
          "Airtel": "Airtel",
          "O2": "O2",
          "Unity Media": "Unity Media"
        },
        "Common Metrics": {
          "NPS": {
            "Nps First Operator": {
              "Score": "Score",
              "Tiers": "Tiers",
              "Scale": "Scale",
              "Top 2 Box": "Top 2 Box",
              "Bottom 2 Box": "Bottom 2 Box",
              "Mean": "Mean"
            },
            "Nps Second Operator": {
              "Score": "Score",
              "Tiers": "Tiers",
              "Scale": "Scale",
              "Top 2 Box": "Top 2 Box",
              "Bottom 2 Box": "Bottom 2 Box",
              "Mean": "Mean"
            }
          },
          "Emotional Attributes": {

          },
          "Emotional Attributes2": {

          }
        },
        "Metrics by Business Area": {
          "Mobile Telephony": {
            "Mobile Telephony sat.": {
              "Score": "Score",
              "Tiers": "Tiers",
              "Scale": "Scale",
              "Top 2 Box": "Top 2 Box",
              "Bottom 2 Box": "Bottom 2 Box",
              "Mean": "Mean"
            },
            "Billing Sat.": {

            },
            "Price Sat.": {

            },
            "Ease of Top Up Sat.": {

            },
            "Buying or Changing Contract Sat.": {

            },
            "Set Up Sat.": {

            },
            "Signal Coverage Sat.": {

            }
          }
        },
        "Demographics": {
          "Gender": {
            "Male": "Male",
            "FeMale": "FeMale"
          },
          "Age Group": {
            "18-30": "18-30",
            "30-50": "30-50"
          },
          "Region": {
            "North": "North",
            "South": "South",
            "East": "East",
            "West": "West"
          },
          "House Hold Composition": {
            "House Hold composition1": "House Hold composition1",
            "House Hold composition2": "House Hold composition2"
          }
        }
      },
      "Nested Measure": {
        "Brand": {
          "Vodafone": "Vodafone",
          "1&1": "1&1",
          "Airtel": "Airtel",
          "O2": "O2",
          "Unity Media": "Unity Media"
        },
        "Common Metrics": {
          "NPS": {
            "Nps First Operator": {
              "Score": "Score",
              "Tiers": "Tiers",
              "Scale": "Scale",
              "Top 2 Box": "Top 2 Box",
              "Bottom 2 Box": "Bottom 2 Box",
              "Mean": "Mean"
            },
            "Nps Second Operator": {
              "Score": "Score",
              "Tiers": "Tiers",
              "Scale": "Scale",
              "Top 2 Box": "Top 2 Box",
              "Bottom 2 Box": "Bottom 2 Box",
              "Mean": "Mean"
            }
          },
          "Emotional Attributes": {

          },
          "Emotional Attributes2": {

          }
        },
        "Metrics by Business Area": {
          "Mobile Telephony": {
            "Mobile Telephony sat.": {
              "Score": "Score",
              "Tiers": "Tiers",
              "Scale": "Scale",
              "Top 2 Box": "Top 2 Box",
              "Bottom 2 Box": "Bottom 2 Box",
              "Mean": "Mean"
            },
            "Billing Sat.": {

            },
            "Price Sat.": {

            },
            "Ease of Top Up Sat.": {

            },
            "Buying or Changing Contract Sat.": {

            },
            "Set Up Sat.": {

            },
            "Signal Coverage Sat.": {

            }
          }
        },
        "Demographics": {
          "Gender": {
            "Male": "Male",
            "FeMale": "FeMale"
          },
          "Age Group": {
            "18-30": "18-30",
            "30-50": "30-50"
          },
          "Region": {
            "North": "North",
            "South": "South",
            "East": "East",
            "West": "West"
          },
          "House Hold Composition": {
            "House Hold composition1": "House Hold composition1",
            "House Hold composition2": "House Hold composition2"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Brand": {
      "Vodafone": "Vodafone",
      "1&1": "1&1",
      "Airtel": "Airtel",
      "O2": "O2",
      "Unity Media": "Unity Media"
    },
    "Metrics": {
      "Common Metrics": {
        "NPS": {
          "Nps First Operator": {
            "Score": "Score",
            "Tiers": "Tiers",
            "Scale": "Scale",
            "Top 2 Box": "Top 2 Box",
            "Bottom 2 Box": "Bottom 2 Box",
            "Mean": "Mean"
          },
          "Nps Second Operator": {
            "Score": "Score",
            "Tiers": "Tiers",
            "Scale": "Scale",
            "Top 2 Box": "Top 2 Box",
            "Bottom 2 Box": "Bottom 2 Box",
            "Mean": "Mean"
          }
        },
        "Emotional Attributes": {

        },
        "Emotional Attributes2": {

        }
      },
      "Metrics by Business Area": {
        "Mobile Telephony": {
          "Mobile Telephony sat.": {
            "Score": "Score",
            "Tiers": "Tiers",
            "Scale": "Scale",
            "Top 2 Box": "Top 2 Box",
            "Bottom 2 Box": "Bottom 2 Box",
            "Mean": "Mean"
          },
          "Billing Sat.": {

          },
          "Price Sat.": {

          },
          "Ease of Top Up Sat.": {

          },
          "Buying or Changing Contract Sat.": {

          },
          "Set Up Sat.": {

          },
          "Signal Coverage Sat.": {

          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Significance Testing": {
      "None": "None",
      "Previous Period": "Previous Period",
      "Previous Year": "Previous Year"
    }
  }
]
```

I need jQuery code to retrieve the data and create the UI dynamically.

Comment: Can you show the structure you want to show using that json ?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the UI?

Comment: It would be a left panel  as shown below

Comment: SO is not a free coding service.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

With `jQuery.parseJSON`you can converts the json string in a object, the code will like this:

```
var objects = jQuery.parseJSON( jsonString );
```

And then you must loop with:

```
objects.forEach(function(item, index, arr) {
    //Do Something
});
```

Comment: Can I get Inner objects also with this?? bcoz I need to add html for every object

Answer (score 0):

The result would be something like this[Clearly it was left panel click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zThcH.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
function nestedLevelPanel(value, i) {
    var sb = "";
    $.each(value, function (key, value) {
        debugger
        sb += "<div class='level_'" + i + "' style='height:60px;width:100%;color:white;'>" + key + "<input style='float:right;' type='checkbox'/></div>";
        if (i>2) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            nestedLevelPanel(value, i + 1);
        }
    });
    $(".panelLevel" + i).append(sb.toString());
}

var i = 0; var sb1 = ""; arrobjects = []; var arrkeys = [];
function buildLeftPanel(data) {
    if ($.isEmptyObject(data)) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        debugger
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            arrobjects.push(value);
            arrkeys.push(key);
            $("#id").html(key);
            sb1 += "<div class='tab' style='height:60px;width:100%;color:white;'>" + key + "</div>";
            nestedLevelPanel(value, 2);
            console.log(key);
        });
        $(".panelLevel1").append(sb1.toString());
    }
};
```

I wrote this one